# vbscript search for pattern prefix and return word

Tags: vbscript, hta

Hi I am searching for a particular pattern(Prefix) in File and trying to return the Whole word. There are multiple times the pattern is there in the file

For example: I have a text file that contains text like:-

```
[CATS].[Hello_World] Lorem Ipsum [CATS].[Hi_Venus] Demo Text [CATS].[Yo_Moon] Lorm Ipsum
```

There is no proper line in the text file, means one line may contain 
entire thing so returning line is problematic.
Programm should return [Hello_World], [Hi_Venus], [Yo_Moon] for matching pattern [CATS].

My Cureent code(.hta file) is:-

```
Dim sStartPath, sStartFile, sFilter, sCaption, filePath
sStartPath = "D:\Remote"
sStartFile = sStartPath & "\nul"
sFilter    = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|" _
  & "VBScript (*.vbs;*.vbc)|*.vbs;*.vbc|" _
  & "HTML (*.htm;*.html;*.hta)|*.htm;*.html;*.hta|"
sCaption = "Choose a File:"

Sub ProcessFile()
On Error Resume Next
filePath = document.My_Process_Form.txtfile.value
        Set contents = filePath.OpenAsTextStream
        If err.number = 0 then
        Linenum = 0
        Do Until contents.AtEndOfStream
            line = contents.readline
            Linenum = Linenum + 1
                Test = Instr(line, [CATS]) 
                If Isnull(Test) = false then If Test > 0 then           demo.innerText = "1" & filePath & " " & Linenum
        Loop

        Else
            err.clear
        End If
End Sub
```

I am using it in an hta application with couple of other functions.
This returns file path and line number that contains the pattern. But I want it to search for prefix and return next element as mentioned above.

Comment: `MyArray = Split(line, "[CATS].", -1, 1)`? See [Split Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0764e5w5(v=vs.84).aspx).

Comment: Split() is not good nere, because the input contains text that is neither seperator nor target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a RegExp that looks for text in `[]` preceeded by `[CATS].` As in

```
>> s = "[CATS].[Hello_World] Lorem Ipsum [CATS].[Hi_Venus] Demo Text [CATS].[Yo_Moon] Lorm Ipsum "
>> Set r = New RegExp
>> r.Global = True
>> r.Pattern = "\[CATS\]\.(\[[^]]+\])"
>> Set ms = r.Execute(s)
>> For Each m In ms
>>     WScript.Echo m.SubMatches(0)
>> Next
>>
[Hello_World]
[Hi_Venus]
[Yo_Moon]
```